# TextMate-styles colors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, textmate

Does anyone know a link to a set of color profiles for Eclipse that resemble TextMate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Vibrant Ink](http://blog.codefront.net/2006/09/28/vibrant-ink-textmate-theme-for-eclipse/) TextMate theme for Eclipse, but I didn't have much luck with those before and Eclipse does not really support theming.

Answer (score 1):

http://commentedout.posterous.com/the-typography-of-my-actionscript
http://commentedout.posterous.com/the-typography-of-my-flash-builder
http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/

Hope these help.

Answer (score 1):

http://jan.kuzniak.pl/?p=155 this vibrant ink textmate theme works for my Eclipse 3.6.2